# How to turn off PDO error message

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to use phpunit to test connection, I already make `error_reporting(0)` and assign `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT`, but when I give the wrong information on purpose, it always dump error message, for example, if I give the wrong account, it shows

`PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (us
ing password: YES)`

How to turn it off?

```
$options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE    => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
);
$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $config['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['database'] . ';charset=utf8';

try {
    $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $config['username'], $config['password'], $options);
} catch (PDOExeception $e) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: You are confusing PDO messages which you should NEVER turn off with displaying PHP errors, which you can easily turn off on a live server using a single configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PDO::__construct` will always throw a `PDOException` if the connection fails. There is  nothing you can do about that.  Any sane application should throw exception if it fails to connect or maybe you have good reason to explain why you need to turn off exception on connections.

Beside the connection It will work on others transactions.

**Example:**

```
<?php
$options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE    => PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT,
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
);
$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $config['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['database'] . ';charset=utf8';
try {
    //THIS WILL THROW EXECPTION IF FAILED, NO MATTER WHAT ERROR MODE YOU SET
    $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $config['username'], $config['password'], $options);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    // Do something
}

//JUST SILENT THIS  WILL NOT CAUSE EXCEPTION
$dbh->query("SELECT badColumn FROM wrongTable");
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I was thought SILENT will work when execute `new PDO`, I will turn it on, all I want is check if connection normal, if not, I need to inform admin and show defined message, basically I can't let user see PDO default connection error, but just can't disable it even display_error was closed.

Comment: Go in php.ini and set `display_errors = Off` then restart appache or reboot your server

Comment: I tried, it still display PDO error message, I wrote an error code on purpose to try the `dispaly_errors`, and error message is not come out, so I thinks server config is right~